# How do Facebook group conversations work?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I started a group conversation on Facebook and I want to know a few things about it.

Who can remove someone from the conversation?

I tried it (remove a member from the group I started) and it did work in the messenger.com. Do other members also have the power to remove members including me?

I already checked fb help-center but it was of no use to me.

Comment: _I tried it and it did work in the messenger web interface_, what you tried and what did work? By _messenger web interface_, did you mean messenger.com or normal Facebook chat?

Comment: @serenesat I updated the post. Thanks.